# Duplicate sum between two dates

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find the number of duplicates, and also sum them between two specific dates. But can not implement the criteria for dates on `having` because of the grouping.

Any help will be much appreciated.
This is what I've tried

```
  select AssociationBarcode, 
         count(*) 
    from ContainerInstruction
group by ContainerInstruction.AssociationBarcode
  having count (*) > 1 and 
         AssociationBarcode <> ''
   where CreatedDateTime between getdate() - 1 and getdate()
```

Comment: Your query won't even compile. Also please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: Please provide expected result and sample data.

Comment: May be just move `where` clause before `group by` clause?

Comment: Please do check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query with inline comments which server as explanation:

```
select 
         AssociationBarcode, 
         count(*) as [count],
         sum(yourColumnWhichNeedsToBeSummed) as [Sum]
      from 
         ContainerInstruction
      -- Note that the Where clause containing dates is applied before grouping. 
      -- This also means that your count and sum will be affected by where clause.
      where 
         CreatedDateTime between getdate() - 1 and getdate() and 
         AssociationBarcode <> ''
      group by 
         ContainerInstruction.AssociationBarcode
      having 
        count (*) > 1
```

See a demo fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bab82/3